# Using Ajax with Ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax

I am trying to get back into Ruby, and creating a simple vote up and down system (like reddit).

I can get the votes to work, but the page reloads each time. I am trying to implement an ajax call to change the values dynamically, but the only guides I can find are for Rails. I am just using Ruby with a Sinatra server.

the html.erb

```
<form action="/votes" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<%= post.id %>">
    <button id="thumb-up"><img src="/images/thumbs-up.gif" /></button>
  </form>
    <p> <%= post.votes.count %> </p>
  <form action="/votes" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<%= post.id %>">
    <button id="thumb-down"><img src="/images/thumbs-down.gif" /></button>
  </form>
```

jquery

```
$('#thumb-up').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    url: '/votes',
    method: 'post',
    success: function() {
      console.log('vote up');
      $(this).html("<%= post.votes.count %>");
    }
  })
});
```

and the model

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  validates :post, uniqueness: { scope: :user }
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :post }

end
```

The routes (sorry, added later)

```
post '/votes' do
  if logged_in?
    vote = Vote.new
    vote.user_id = current_user.id
    vote.post_id = params[:post_id]
    vote.save
    redirect to '/'
  else
    redirect to '/session/new'
  end
end

delete '/votes' do
  if logged_in?
    votes = Vote.where(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: params[:post_id])

    votes.each do |vote|
      vote.delete
    end
    redirect to '/'
  else
    redirect to '/session/new'
  end
end
```

Now I'm guessing this is a super simple thing, and I know that remote: true has something to do with it.

At the moment I get a 500 error with the thumb-up button, but not with the thumb-down, which has `url: 'delete'` instead of post.

Can I accomplish this without having a form for each button?

Comment: Hint: Study some beginning ajax tutorials and try to find one where the syntax `<%= post.votes.count %>` is introduced.

Comment: `remote: true` is a Rails convenience thing that does Ajax for you. Sinatra does not have anything comparable. You are mostly doing okay, with minor errors (some of them conceptual). `500` means error in your server code - and you didn't post your Sinatra routes, so we can't say anything about them. As @7stud says, your `$(this).html` should likely pass something that was in Ajax response, and not something pre-rendered (or even worse, unrendered).

Comment: *Can I accomplish this without having a form for each button?* Yes.  A button doesn't need a form to exist on an html page.  And a button can be clicked without there being a form on the page.  But, you have to be able to use code to identify which button was clicked, e.g. checking its id, so that you can tell the server what to do in your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here:

```
validates :post, uniqueness: { scope: :user }
```

and here

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/votes',
    method: 'post',
    success: function() {
      console.log('vote up');
      $(this).html("<%= post.votes.count %>");
    }
  })
```

Your vote requires a post id, but you don't send one in your ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

I had worked on same thing, its easy if u ajax call like this

```
<%= link_to image_tag(likepic), like_post_path(post,status: true),  class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true %>
```

like_user_path goes to "like" method in post controller and posts status:true means "liked"

hope it works, because it worked for me

and the model is

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: He's not using rails, so `like_post_path` won't be accessible. As well as `remote: true`

Comment: oh sorry, i dint see